# Which system calls made by NTP affect the CLOCK_MONOTONIC?

Tags: clock, ntp

I have been looking for an answer to this one but no clear documentation yet.

The `CLOCK_MONOTONIC` from `clock_gettime` man page says that it's affected by incremental adjustments performed by `adjtime` and NTP

> CLOCK_MONOTONIC
>
> ```
> Clock  that  cannot  be set and represents monotonic time since some unspecified
> starting point. This clock is not affected by discontinuous jumps in the system
> time (e.g.,  if  the  system  administrator manually  changes  the  clock),
> but is affected by the incremental adjustments performed by adjtime(3) and NTP
> ```

What is not clear to me is that is it affected by all sorts of adjustments made by NTP or just the small adjustements ?

Say if there is a big time jump made by NTP, if the system was way off the clock, will `CLOCK_MONOTONIC` reflect that ?

I am not sure which of the following [system calls](http://www.ntp.org/ntpfaq/NTP-s-algo.htm#Q-CLOCK-DISCIPLINE) NTP makes to adjust the time on my Cent OS system

A quick test showed no change in monotonic clock output even though NTP made the system jump by 10 hours.

Even making the time jump by `clock_settime` call didn't affect MONOTONIC time

Comment: adjtime() gradually adjusts the system clock, as does NTP under "normal" conditions.  However, NTP will sometimes "step"/"jump" the clock (if it detects a peer offsset too great for too long a period).  So, it sounds like CLOCK_MONOTONIC filters out "steps"/"jumps", which would tend to make it at least more monotonic than otherwise in the event of "steps"/"jumps".